# run function of fetching data after onclick

Tags: javascript, json

I have function that retrieve the `JSON` data

I want to add button if clicked the `json` data show

Part of the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value = "Submit" id = "Submit" onclick="appendData(data)" >
    <div id="myData"></div>
    <script>
        fetch('quizQuestions.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })  
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })

        function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  var div = document.createElement("div");

}


  }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to run the `appendData` when user click submit .  i tried `onclick` but function is running without clicking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean fetch and append on click

NOTE, I changed the button to a button instead of submit

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("Submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
    fetch('quizQuestions.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        appendData(data);
      })
  })
});

function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = data;
  mainContainer.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="Submit">
<div id="myData"></div>
```

OR fetch and append onload but reveal on click?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  fetch('quizQuestions.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      appendData(data);
    });
  document.getElementById("Submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
     document.querySelector("myData > div").classList.toggle("hide")
  })
});

function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = data;
  div.classList.add("hide"); // CSS: .hide { display: none; }
  mainContainer.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="Submit">
<div id="myData"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove function calling after `then`. It immediately calls your function after success.

You can store data in a variable and on click of that button you can append the data in the `div`.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head> </head>
    <body>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" onclick="appendData()" />
      <div id="myData"></div>
      <script>
        var fetchData = '';
        fetch('quizQuestions.json')
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function (data) {
            fetchData = data;
          });

        function appendData() {
          var mainContainer = document.getElementById('myData');
          mainContainer.innerHTML = fetchData;
        }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You can manage to click that before there is any data to show...